# Can't concatenate str to bytes error while posting data to api in Python

Tags: python, http

I have post api url as below:

https://az-us-eu-dev-sgtps-apilayer.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=sqEdwsf6vapdcPnI9zxwlwXHw==

I am posting json data to it and I am getting proper response with code 200.

I have to do the same from python and I am using below code:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('az-us-eu-dev-sgtps-apilayer.azurewebsites.net')

conn.request("POST", "/api/HttpTrigger1?code=sqEdwsf6vapdcPnI9zxwlwXHw==", jdata, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
rdata = response.read()
rdata = rdata.decode('utf8')
rdata = json.loads(rdata)
```

but on 3rd line above, I am getting below error:

```
can't concat str to bytes
```

I tried doing this:

```
url = "/api/HttpTrigger1?code=sqEdwsf6vapdcPnI9zxwlwXHw=="
new_url = str.encode(url)
conn.request("POST", new_url, jdata, headers)
```

Below is the `jdata` which is json data to be posted to the api url:

```
{
    "reqType": "True",
    "date": "27-09-2019"
}
```

But it shows same error. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Please consider using the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) module :)

Comment: And could you update the question with what is `jdata`, and maybe check it's `type` too ?

Comment: @hansolo I have udpated the question.

Comment: @hansolo Can you give an example for `request` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module like,

```
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> endpoint = 'https://az-us-eu-dev-sgtps-apilayer.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=sqEdwsf6vapdcPnI9zxwlwXHw=='
>>> jdata = {"reqType": "True", "date": "27-09-2019"}
>>> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
>>> r = requests.post(endpoint, data=json.dumps(jdata), headers=headers)
```

> Instead of encoding the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly
>   using the json parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be
>   encoded automatically:

```
>>> r = requests.post(endpoint, json=jdata, headers=headers)
>>> r.json() # for response
```

Comment: Thanks. I have got the 200 ok response but havent got the data. At `r.json()`, it shows error `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Then the endpoint is not responding with correct JSON. It's broken json, and possibly the fault of the endpoint. You can check the `r.content`

Comment: Endpoint cannot be wrong, as I have tested this non Postman and I get proper response with data.

Comment: Could you check the content of `r.text` ?

Comment: `r.content` is empty `b''`

Comment: So, i guess it is returning empty string :/

Comment: `r.text` is empty. Don't know whats wrong as in postman, its all working fine.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the postman, with the necessary contents in view ?

Comment: My bad. `jdata` was dict. I used `json.dumps()` to convert it into str and got the response. Thanks